# Openstack development using SDK - auth_url does not work

Tags: openstack, devstack

Getting into openstack dev using [this link](https://developer.openstack.org/firstapp-libcloud/getting_started.html), and turns out my auth_url is of the form `http://192.168.43.18/identity/v3` from the openstack RC yaml file. When I use it, as used in the link, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conn_tester.py", line 22, in <module>
    images = conn.list_images()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/openstack.py", line 282, in list_images
    self.connection.request('/images/detail').object, ex_only_active)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/openstack.py", line 223, in request
    raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 536, in request
    action = self.morph_action_hook(action)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/openstack.py", line 290, in morph_action_hook
    self._populate_hosts_and_request_paths()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/openstack.py", line 324, in _populate_hosts_and_request_paths
    osa = osa.authenticate(**kwargs)  # may throw InvalidCreds
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/openstack_identity.py", line 855, in authenticate
    return self._authenticate_2_0_with_password()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/openstack_identity.py", line 880, in _authenticate_2_0_with_password
    return self._authenticate_2_0_with_body(reqbody)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/openstack_identity.py", line 885, in _authenticate_2_0_with_body
    method='POST')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 637, in request
    response = responseCls(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 157, in __init__
    message=self.parse_error())
libcloud.common.exceptions.BaseHTTPError: {"error": {"message": "get_version_v3() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'", "code": 400, "title": "Bad Request"}}
```

I have tried changing the auth url to `http://192.168.43.18:35357` and also port 5000, but I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.43.18', port=35357): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.0/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe06f7dff90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Using devstack version `16.0.0`

Python code:

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver

auth_username = 'demo'
auth_password = 'password'
#auth_url = 'http://controller:5000'
auth_url = 'http://192.168.43.18:35357'
#auth_url = 'http://192.168.43.18/identity/v3/'
project_name = 'demo'
region_name = 'RegionOne'

provider = get_driver(Provider.OPENSTACK)
conn = provider(auth_username,
                auth_password,
                ex_force_auth_url=auth_url,
                ex_force_auth_version='2.0_password',
                ex_tenant_name=project_name,
                ex_force_service_region=region_name)


#print "hello"
images = conn.list_images()
for image in images:
    print(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could specify v3 instead:

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver

auth_username = 'demo'
auth_password = 'password'
auth_url = 'http://192.168.43.18:5000'
project_name = 'demo'
region_name = 'RegionOne'

provider = get_driver(Provider.OPENSTACK)
conn = provider(auth_username,
                auth_password,
                ex_force_auth_url=auth_url,
                ex_force_auth_version='3.x_password',
                ex_tenant_name=project_name,
                ex_force_service_region=region_name)


#print "hello"
images = conn.list_images()
for image in images:
print(image)
```

There aren't many examples using v3. A tenant would normally be associated with 2.0, so I'm not sure if the ex_tenant_name option is required.

Keystone versioning:

https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/

More information on libcloud:

https://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compute/drivers/openstack.html#connecting-to-the-openstack-installation

Also, you can see if keystone is using v2.0:

```
curl http://192.168.43.18:5000/v2.0
```

If it is, then I would assume something like this would work:

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver

auth_username = 'demo'
auth_password = 'password'
auth_url = 'http://192.168.43.18:5000'
project_name = 'demo'
region_name = 'RegionOne'

provider = get_driver(Provider.OPENSTACK)
conn = provider(auth_username,
                auth_password,
                ex_force_auth_url=auth_url,
                ex_force_auth_version='2.0_password',
                ex_tenant_name=project_name,
                ex_force_service_region=region_name)


#print "hello"
images = conn.list_images()
for image in images:
    print(image)
```

If it still isn't working, verify that you are using the public keystone endpoint. Depending on your version, you may receive a different level of information:

```
openstack endpoint list --long
```

or

```
openstack endpoint list
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Tried them, still does not work. When I try the curl command without a port, I get some html back, which says `404 not found`. `/v2.0 was not found on this server`. When I try it with a port, (5000 or 35357), i get connection refused. This maybe due to exceeding maximum tries. If possible, is there  a way of clearing previous attempts? I believe the issue lies in too many failed attempts, which is giving me the `max tries exceeded with url..` error message.